# Create a new document with url scheme in a cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, url-scheme

I implemented a custom URL scheme in a Mac cocoa app.  It works but I'm having a couple issues.

1) Where do I place this code in a document based app to handle the URL events?  I have it in my `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` but it doesn't work if the app is closed since a document hasn't been setup yet.

```
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

2) How do I send the parsed data from the URL to the new document?  I'm creating the new document from my `-handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:` method like this.

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] newDocument:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Where do I place this code in a document based app to handle the URL events?

Most likely in your application delegates applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

2) How do I send the parsed data from the URL to the new document?

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event 
       withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent {
    NSString *urlString = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", urlString);
    NSString *httpString = [urlString substringFromIndex:7];
    NSLog(@“HTTP URL: %@", httpString);
    [self openNewDocumentAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:httpString]];
}

- (void)openNewDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL {
    NSDocumentController *docController = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
    [docController newDocument:nil];
    [(ResponseDocument *)[docController currentDocument] updateURL:absoluteURL];
}
```